# AlloyDB- CREATE DATABASE can not be run in a transaction block

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic, google-alloydb

Since AlloyDB does not support creating a database using terraform yet, I am trying to create it using Alembic and sqlAlchemy. I am using `postgresql+psycopg2` as the driver.My code looks similar to the only answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847829/postgres-pg8000-create-database).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
dburl = "postgresql+psycopg2://user:pswd@myip:5432/postgres/"
engine = create_engine(dburl)
conn = engine.connect()

con.rollback()  # Make sure we're not in a transaction
con.autocommit = True  # Turn on autocommit

conn.execute("CREATE DATABASE qux")
 
con.autocommit = False  # Turn autocommit back off again
```

However, I am getting an error `sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction) CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block`. Can someone suggest how can this be fixed?

Comment: There appears to be a specific package to get connections to AlloyDB (https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-alloydb-connector/) and that uses pg8000 instead of psycopg2.  I would give that a try.

Comment: @Malcolm The connector you mentioned does not support IAM users with AlloyDB as of now. You can check https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-python-connector/issues/151#issuecomment-1794909729

Comment: @GabeWeiss Let me try this

Comment: @GabeWeiss It worked thanks

Comment: @SumitDesai Perfect, I'll mark this as a duplicate of the other one!

Comment: Yes, it does, you can mark it as duplicate